# Getting a representative sample from sorted data

Tags: sampling

I'd like to sample a Market Place API which for each call returns a group of items sorted by relevance or price. I can get up to 100 items per call.

Another issue is that the items are organized by a hierarchical structure of categories and I'd like to get a sample by category.

The first thing that comes to my mind is to make calls to the API by randomizing the offset. For example the first call could be /products/?catid='notebooks'&limit=100&offset=343. But the result(the 100 items) will be sorted by some metric and I guess it would compromise the "representativeness" of the sample.

Comment: Is your problem that you want to do this with a limited number of calls to the API? If this isn't an issue at all, you could just ask for only one item per call at random offsets (assuming you can find the max number of items).

Comment: @Dougal Yes, the idea is to get near to real time stats about categories sales and this won't be possible if I've to make one call per item.